# How do you restrict a specific band of frequencies in a signal using a filter in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to design a filter in MATLAB that performs the following steps:

1. First, generate random data in the UHF band (for example 750 MHz to 800 MHz)
2. I want to filter my data exactly at 790 MHz.

I am new to MATLAB, but I have generated random data using `rand` but what is my next step?

Comment: A bit more explanation please..?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about filter design, not software programming.  Once you design a filter, implementation of that filter in MATLAB would be a suitable question for StackOverflow.  You could also ask on our sister sites [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we start, I am assuming this is a digital filter.  As such, I'm assuming you'll need to know the sampling frequency that you are acquiring your data.  Let's call this `Fs` for now.  Also, we must make sure that your sampling frequency is at least twice your bandwidth.  In this case, it should be `> 1600 MHz`.  Now onto your questions:

## Step #1 - Generate Noise

You can use the Additive White Gaussian Noise generate method (`awgn`) to do that for you.  I'm using AWGN as this is a good model for modeling most noise in communication systems.This **adds** AWGN noise on top of your signal, and so if you just want the noisy component, simply specify **zero** as the input.  You will need to specify the SNR though and you'll need to know this before hand.  However, if we want a really noisy signal, let's specify the SNR as 0 dB.    The power spectral density of AWGN noise is a completely flat band at all frequencies.  As such, once you create your AWGN noise signal, you can band-pass filter your noise so that it lies within 750 to 800 MHz.  I also chose AWGN as it's flexible, and you can bandpass wherever you like, seeing as it has a flat power spectral density.  You can use the `butter` command to create your numerator and denominator coefficients for your bandpass filter.  You call it as so:

```
[b,a] = butter(n, Wn, 'ftype');
```

`Wn` for us is a 2 element vector that corresponds to the lower and upper frequencies you wish to filter.  This also must be **normalized** such that the sampling frequency is assigned a frequency of 1.  Therefore, your lower and upper frequencies in normalized range should be as follows:

```
BW = Fs / 2; %// Units of MHz
lower = (750/BW); 
upper = (800/BW);
```

`'ftype'` is the type of filter you want.  In this case, you want a bandpass filter, so specify `'bandpass'` as the flag.  As for the order `n`, that you'll have to play around with.  Try something like 7 or 9 first.  This totally depends on what your frequency distribution of your signal looks like.

Now you have that established, call the `butter` function to get the filter coefficients.

```
n = 7;
[b,a] = butter(n, [lower upper], 'bandpass');
```

Now that's complete, filter your signal like so.  Let's say `x` was the signal you have generated through AWGN.  You would do it like so:

```
numPoints = 1000; %// Need to know number of points before hand
x = awgn(zeros(numPoints,1), 0);
```

Now, filter your signal:

```
outFilter = filter(b, a, x);
```

## Step #2 - Filter at exactly 790 MHz

You can specify a **notch** filter to filter your noise for you.  We know what frequency we wish to filter at, which is 790 MHz.  As such:

```
notchFreq = (790 / BW);
```

We also need to specify the bandwidth of the filter.  Usually, we set this so that a Q factor of 35 is satisfied.  As such:

```
bwFilter = notchFreq / 35;
```

We thus construct our notch filter like so, using a second order IIR notch filter generation method

```
[b2,a2] = iirnotch(notchFreq, bwFilter);
```

Now, we finally filter the method from Step #1 like so:

```
outFinal = filter(b2, a2, outFilter);
```

This should hopefully give you what you need.  You may need to play around with the parameters a bit, as I have no idea what they are for your applications.  The thing with signal processing is that you need to keep tuning your parameters until you get the best results for your application.  Good luck!

## References

- http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/iirnotch.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html

Comment: @user3607520 You are most welcome.  If this post has helped you in any way, please consider accepting my answer.  You may do this by going to the top of my post, and on the left where the up and down arrows are, click on the checkmark.

Comment: Sir,I want to design a filter,your answer is most helpful to me

Comment: I think I pretty much answered how you want to design your filter.  You gave me the specs, and I provided you a procedure on how to do it.  Good luck

Comment: hello sir, Is there any chance to change the simulation design to matlab code, ineed to change the commdvbt to matlab code is it possible. Advance Regards

Comment: @user3607520 - No and this will be the last time I reply to you.  Good luck.